# How to automatically modify variable names in ruby and javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I want do something like:

```
for(var i=0; i < 3, i++) {
  var file_i = i;
}
```

and got local variables: file_0 = 0,file_1 = 1, file_2 =2

I'm also want to know how to make it happen in Ruby.

Comment: Don't do this. Just ... don't. Dynamically generated variable names just lead to hair-ripping-out and chewing-on-carpet fits of rage when you can't figure out why something's broken.

Comment: ... and then god gave us [`Arrays`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the new variables being global:

```
for(var i=0; i < 3, i++) {
  window["file_" + i] = i;
}
```

But as comments have noted, this is a bad idea.  Make these properties of an object:

```
var files = { };
for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {  // <-------- typo there.  Should be a ; after i < 3
    files["file_" + i] = i;
}
```

And then you can read back these properties with:

```
for (var key in files) {
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(files, key))
        alert(key + " " + files[key]); 
}
```

I'm afraid I don't know how to do this with Ruby.

Comment: object is the way to go thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
var listVar = [];

for(var i=0; i < 3, i++) {
  listVar["file_"+i] = i;
}

alert(listVar["file_1"]);// or file_2...
```